# regex failed to strip the string

Tags: regex

I've got a camel endpoint uri as

```
file:///test/csv?sortBy=file:name&include=.*.csv&move=done
```

I'm using a regex to parse just the file name, the regex I used is `.*?:(.*)\??.*`

but its failing to strip the options and returning the whole string

```
///test/csv?sortBy=file:name&include=.*.csv&move=done
```

whereas the expected result is `///test/csv`

what is wrong with my pattern

Comment: you are making `?` optional

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use a regex to parse the URI, I suggest you use the functionality that no doubt it exists in whatever language you're using.

If you're in PHP, http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

If you're in Perl, use the URI module: http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI.pm

Better to use existing, tested code than writing your own, and make no mistake, regexes are code.

Answer (score 0):

You must not include anything in the pattern that will consume the question mark and beyond, i.e. the issue is that you match a literal question mark and everything behind it with `\?.*`

Instead, you can match everything except question marks:

```
^.*?:([^?]*)
```

This will match everything until the first question mark is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `(.*)`, use `([^?]*)` That will match until there's a `?`.

It's what you need to change.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem, the pattern would still match everything.

Comment: Do you realize that we ended up with the same solution?

Comment: No, I didn't because it's different. I changed more than what your post mentions.

Comment: @phant0m: No, this is a valid solution. The result is in the capturing group. It doesn't matter if the whole regex matches more.

Comment: @nhahtdh Correct, but that should be mentioned. There's no point in consuming anything more than what is necessary.

Comment: And what don't you understand of "Instead of using `(.*)`"?

Comment: I think he nitpicks about the `\??.*` part that you left alone.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
^[^:]+:([^\?]+)
```

[Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/w1bEHTbs55)

Comment: If you want to include protocol in match, why then not just `^[^\?]+` ? (http://www.rubular.com/r/dRVaGlu53I)

Comment: This regex is only capturing `///test/csv` (without protocol), please check the demo link (provided in answer).

Comment: Huh - not really. Regex match protocol as well, just group (#1) does not include that... Check my answer to see a difference!

Answer (score 0):

You're using far too many `.*` where you should have something more specific:

```
^[a-z]+:([^?#]*)
```

Your pattern uses `(.*)`, so it tries to match the whole string first. Then it gets to `\??`, which is an optional question mark (so it's fine if it's missing), then `.*`, which is an optional anything. The end result is `(.*)` matching everything.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure **which file name you mean**, if the request uri, or one that is as a parameter.

---

If the request uri, then use:

```
(?<=\/)[^\/][^\?]+
```

Check **[this demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/Zr3htNRAzK)**.

And if the one from parameter list, then go with:

```
(?<==file:)[^&]+
```

Check **[this demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/ZspxuWf2GI)**.